# Update method not saving changes Sqlite Database (Android Studio)

Tags: java, database, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I'm trying to complete my update method on my database, but I'm not getting the results.
My app doesn't show any error, I can access the object I want to edit, I'm able to change the data, but the changes are not saved.
I've tried this code in another app and worked ok, but now I'm not able to save my changes when I edit the data I want to alter.
Can anyone please give a hand?

**My Database:**

```
package com.myapplication.umdocededaisy;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    List<MateriaPrima> listaProduto = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BancoDoceDaisy.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    //Estruturas das Tabelas do banco de dados:

    //Tabela dos produtos - materia prima:
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUTO = "materia_prima";
    private static final String COLUMN_CODIGO = "codigo";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUTO = "produto";
    private static final String COLUMN_VALOR = "valor";
    private static final String COLUMN_QTD = "quantidade";
    private static final String COLUMN_TIPO = "tipo";
    //------------------------------------------------------

    MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_PRODUTO +
                " (" + COLUMN_CODIGO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_PRODUTO + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_VALOR + " FLOAT, " +
                COLUMN_QTD + " FLOAT, " +
                COLUMN_TIPO + " TEXT); ";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUTO);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addMateriaPrima(MateriaPrima materiaPrima) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_PRODUTO, materiaPrima.getProduto());
        cv.put(COLUMN_VALOR, materiaPrima.getValor());
        cv.put(COLUMN_QTD, materiaPrima.getQuantidade());
        cv.put(COLUMN_TIPO, materiaPrima.getTipo());

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_PRODUTO, null, cv);
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strAddSucess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        db.close();
    }

    Cursor readAllData(){
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUTO;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(db != null){
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public List<MateriaPrima> buscaProduto() {
        String columns[] = {COLUMN_CODIGO, COLUMN_PRODUTO, COLUMN_VALOR, COLUMN_QTD, COLUMN_TIPO};
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUTO, columns, null, null, null,null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CODIGO);
            int codigo = cursor.getInt(index1);
            int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRODUTO);
            String produto = cursor.getString(index2);
            int index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_VALOR);
            float valor = cursor.getFloat(index3);
            int index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QTD);
            float quantidade = cursor.getFloat(index4);
            int index5 = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIPO);
            String tipo = cursor.getString(index5);
            MateriaPrima produtos = new MateriaPrima(codigo, produto, valor, quantidade, tipo);
            listaProduto.add(produtos);
        }
        return listaProduto;
    }

    void updateData(MateriaPrima materiaPrima) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRODUTO, materiaPrima.getProduto());
        cv.put(COLUMN_VALOR, materiaPrima.getValor());
        cv.put(COLUMN_QTD, materiaPrima.getQuantidade());
        cv.put(COLUMN_TIPO, materiaPrima.getTipo());

        long result = db.update(TABLE_PRODUTO, cv, " codigo=?",  new String[]{String.valueOf(materiaPrima.getCodigo())});
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strSucess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        db.close();
    }

    void deleteOneRow(String materiaPrima) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long result = db.delete(TABLE_PRODUTO, COLUMN_CODIGO + " codigo", new String[]{String.valueOf(materiaPrima)});
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strSucess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        db.close();
    }

    void deleteAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUTO);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**My Update Activity**

```
package com.myapplication.umdocededaisy;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editCodigo2, editProduto2, editValor2, editQuantidade2, editTipo2;
    Button btnUpdate, btnDelete;
    String codigo, produto, valor, quantidade, tipo;
    InputMethodManager inputManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        //Declarações objetos:
        editCodigo2 = findViewById(R.id.editCodigo2);
        editProduto2 = findViewById(R.id.editProduto2);
        editValor2 = findViewById(R.id.editValor2);
        editQuantidade2 = findViewById(R.id.editQuantidade2);
        editTipo2 = findViewById(R.id.editTipo2);
        btnUpdate = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        btnDelete = findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        getAndSetIntentData();

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if(ab != null){
            ab.setTitle(produto);
        }

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            MateriaPrima materiaPrima = new MateriaPrima();
            MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase(UpdateActivity.this);
            produto = editProduto2.getText().toString().trim();
            valor = editValor2.getText().toString().trim();
            quantidade = editQuantidade2.getText().toString().trim();
            tipo = editTipo2.getText().toString().trim();
            myDB.updateData(materiaPrima);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(btnUpdate.getWindowToken(), 0);
            recreate();
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(v -> confirmDeleteDialog());

    }

    void getAndSetIntentData() {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("codigo") && getIntent().hasExtra("produto") && getIntent().hasExtra("valor") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("quantidade") && getIntent().hasExtra("tipo")){
            //Getting data:
            codigo = getIntent().getStringExtra("codigo");
            produto = getIntent().getStringExtra("produto");
            valor = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");
            quantidade = getIntent().getStringExtra("quantidade");
            tipo = getIntent().getStringExtra("tipo");

            //Setting data:
            editCodigo2.setText(codigo);
            editProduto2.setText(produto);
            editValor2.setText(valor);
            editQuantidade2.setText(quantidade);
            editTipo2.setText(tipo);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.strData0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void confirmDeleteDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.strMsgDelete) + " " + produto);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.strMsgDelete ) + " " + produto + " ?");
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.strYes), (dialog, which) -> {
            MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase(UpdateActivity.this);
            myDB.deleteOneRow(codigo);
            finish();
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.strNo), (dialog, which) -> {

        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the changes are not saved? Did you run a SELECT statement after the update and printed the row? Did you extract the db from the device to inspect it?

Comment: Yes, and I have a recycler views showing the list of entries. When I add everything shows correctly, but I' m not able tô sabe my update changes.

Comment: What you see in the recyclerview may or may not reflect the actual data in the table. Extract the database from the device and inspect it.

Comment: I extracted, and still no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct the error by rewriting my update method:

```
void updateData(String row_id, String produto, String valor, String quantidade, String tipo){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRODUTO, produto);
        cv.put(COLUMN_VALOR, valor);
        cv.put(COLUMN_QTD, quantidade);
        cv.put(COLUMN_TIPO, tipo);

        long result = db.update(TABLE_PRODUTO, cv, "codigo=?", new String[]{row_id});
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strSucess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        db.close();
    }
```

**Thanks for all the help**

Comment: Your code is wrong. `update()` never returns -1.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it's working perfectly, and when I replace the 0 for 1 the app crashes.

Comment: If the app crashes you should check the error log and fix the problem. And just to be clear. The app would not crash because you change `if(result == -1)` to `if(result == 0)`.

Comment: You are right maybe there was something wrong before, cause now I changed again the 0 for 1, and it still works, but it was working perfectly fine before also. But thanks any how. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you think that the table is not updated because you see the toast with the message that the update failed.

But, the condition that you check in order to show the correct message is not correct.
The method [`update()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) returns either the number of the rows affected (updated) or `0` if the update failed.
It never returns `-1`.

Change your code like this:

```
if (result == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.strSucess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also, in the listener of `btnUpdate` you define a `MateriaPrima` object which you pass to `updateData()` without setting its properties.
Where do you get the `Codigo` property from?

Change to this:

```
btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    MateriaPrima materiaPrima = new MateriaPrima();
    MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase(UpdateActivity.this);

    materiaPrima.setCodigo(?????); // you must set this property   

    materiaPrima.setProduto(editProduto2.getText().toString().trim());
    materiaPrima.setValor(editValor2.getText().toString().trim());
    materiaPrima.setQuantidade(editQuantidade2.getText().toString().trim());
    materiaPrima.setTipo(editTipo2.getText().toString().trim());

    myDB.updateData(materiaPrima);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(btnUpdate.getWindowToken(), 0);
    recreate();
});
```

Comment: I had no change. Still appears the message of success, but no changes.

Comment: When I `setCodigo` like you said, the object selected comes empty I think because codigo is AutoIncrement and can't be changed. But even after I pass the proprieties from my variables the result is still the same, success but don't save changes. Also I can't set `(result == 0)`, it displays a error: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length.

Comment: With setCodigo() you must pass the value of the column `codigo` which is the id of the row that you want to update. Do you know that value? If not, you can't update the row.

Comment: I don't want to setCodigo(), I just want the codigo to be display so I know the Id of the item I want to edit and save the changes I make. I'm able to show the values correctly, but not able to save the changes, and the app doesn't show any errors it just doesn't save.

Comment: @MarthaAndrade by setCodigo() you don't change the id. You must set it so that it is passed to the query's WHERE clause to find the correct row and update it.